Is it possible to recreate the Source Engine's $phongwarptexture iridescence in Blender?
I am trying to recreate the appearance of the Discouragement Redirection Cube from Portal 2 in Blender 4.2 — specifically, the iridescence property of the the Phong shader used in the Source Engine.

The in-game model uses this material setup:
vertexlitgeneric
{
$baseTexture "models/props/reflecto_cube_glass"
$bumpmap "models/props/reflecto_cube_glass_normal"
$translucent 1
$multipass 1
$refractamount 1

$cloakfactor 1
$cloaktint "[ .1 .1 .1 ]"
$detail "models/props/reflecto_cube_interior"
$detailblendmode 0

$envmap env_cubemap
$normalmapalphaenvmapmask 1
$envmaptint "[ .1 .1 .1 ]"
$envmapconstrast 1

$phong 1
$phongexponent 2
$phongboost 4
$phongfresnelranges "[1 .5 .3]"
$phongwarptexture "models/props/reflecto_cube_iridescence"
$nodecal 1
$forcephong 1
}

The Valve Developer Wiki describes how the $phongwarptexture is applied:

The highlight is multiplied with a texture. The coordinates of the sampled pixel are as follows:
x: 1 - (distance to the center of the highlight)
y: 1 - (fresnel component as computed by Phong Fresnel ranges)


I have the texture file for the iridescence (included below), but I can't figure out how to apply it in Blender. It seems likely I'll need to somehow use Blender's Fresnel node for the $y$-component, but I have no idea what to use for the $x$-component's "distance to the center of the highlight".


Not exactly. Not with regular Blender's shaders. There is no Phong shader in Blender. Rendering is way more advanced nowadays. At least in EEVEE and Cycles. You could still use the map as a reflection map to get an equivalent with more modern shaders:

This doesn't work exactly the same though and I don't think that map was intended to be used as reflection map.
You could try making it more primitive by not using Fresnel, disabling environment, using single light source, just using Normal for texture coordinates and switching to "Standard" view transform in color management settings:

It's still not the same and the ironical part is that it renders way longer than a Phong shader would.

Your screenshots look like good approximations, but when I copy your node setups I don't get the same results. It looks like the texture file is just being applied like a normal UV-mapped texture instead of being applied based on the viewing angle.

OK, well, I didn't fake the screenshots, they are real, so... I don't really know what I could do. Make sure the Texture Coordinate is connected correctly...

What's the purpose of all this you are trying to do? Maybe I could advice further if I understood the situation better.

My goal is to recreate a Discouragement Redirection Cube in Blender for use in a Portal-fan-animation. I didn't mean to imply you'd faked your screenshots, but rather that I must be missing something when I try to copy your setup (maybe some behind-the-scenes setting is different?)... or perhaps it's just that what looks good enough in a screenshot of a monkey model fails to hold up on the actual cube when I can move it around and see how it looks from dynamic angles.
